# Finding the energy of the turtle when it is in motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, mass-energy

I want to solve part c of the following problem.

[image: Problem]

Now, the question tells us to find the energy when the turtle is in motion. Don't we have to find the kinetic energy?  Instead, what the book does is it finds the equivalent energy of its mass.

[image: Problem]

Now, the question didn't ask for this. They want to know what the energy is when the turtle is *in motion*. The turtle doesn't need to be in motion for the equivalent energy of its mass to exist. So, isn't the book doing the problem wrong?

Comment: Please post everything needed for the question directly rather than links to the content. If the links ever become broken then future users will not be able to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question itself is a bit badly worded, because it only asks for *the energy* without specifying which energy. From the answer it is clear that they mean the *total energy* consisting of the energy equivalent of the rest mass and the relativistic kinetic energy. This total energy is the same as the energy equivalent of the relativistic mass, as used in the answer.

Comment: Trick question; the turtle turns into a tortoise half way through!

Comment: In regards to your edit on the main post, note that images are not accessible to all users. The text in the images should be directly put into the post. Also, it is somewhat better to let the OP edit the post after it has been closed so they can make other improvements. Your edit puts the question into the reopen queue without the post really being fixed content-wise, so it gives the post a worse chance of being reopened should the OP make further edits.

Comment: I wasn't aware that any edit will put it in the reopen queue. I'm not going to type the OPs images for him, but moving them into the post was a quick edit to at least make it somewhat readable.